# Como posso escrever os dados gerardos em linhas diferentes?

Tags: python, tkinter

Exemplo: Quero um numero em uma linha, depois em outra linha.

Mas tudo dentro do mesmo arquivo de texto gerado.

```
from tkinter import*


janela = Tk()


#################Cria o arquivo##########################

def nomearq():
    arquivo = open(nameet.get(), 'w')
###########insere os dados no arquivo#############################

def esc():

  arquivo = open(nameet.get(), 'r') 
  conteudo = arquivo.readlines()
  conteudo.append(etmat.get()) 

  arquivo = open(nameet.get(), 'w')
  arquivo.writelines(conteudo)
  arquivo.close()
#############################################
mat = Label(janela, text="matricula:")
mat.grid(row=1, column=1)

etmat = Entry(janela,)
etmat.grid(row=1, column=2)

##############################################

namearq = Label(janela, text="nome do arquivo:")
namearq.grid(row=2, column=1)

nameet = Entry(janela,)
nameet.grid(row=2, column=2)

##############################################

Com = Button(text="Comfirmar", command=esc
             )
Com.grid(row=3,column=2)

##############################################

ger = Button(text="Gerar txt", command=nomearq)
ger.grid(row=4,column=2)




janela.geometry('300x300')
janela.mainloop
```

Answer (score 1):

A forma mais simples de efetuar essa quebra de linha é utilizando o \n:

```
def esc():
  arquivo = open(nameet.get(), 'r') 
  conteudo = arquivo.readlines()
  conteudo.append(etmat.get() + '\n') 

  arquivo = open(nameet.get(), 'w')
  arquivo.writelines(conteudo)
  arquivo.close()
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo me ajudou muito